# Can I hide html5 video tag on everything but desktops?

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-video

Is there a way to do that? I don't want the video showing up on tablets or phones.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/best-way-to-detect-handheld-device-in-jquery - Here is good answer for your question

Comment: Even if it is hidden, it is most likely still going to download.

Comment: Not in iOS, but maybe in android, blackberry, etc. I'm trying to find a solution because the iPad doesn't seem capable of having a poster frame unfortunately. It's always just a black box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. detect width with css media queries or JS
2. android tablets have "mobile" in their browser user agent , ios is easy to detect.
3. detect support for the video tag with [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS media queries like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 680px)
{
    .video { display : none; }
}
```

This will hide the class .video for all screens up to 680px wide

Edit: You can of course also do this the other way around, and set `.video` to `display: none` by default, and then use `min-width` inside a media query to actually show it from a certain width.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with media queries:

```
<div id="video">
  //Video here
</div>

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

    #video {
      visibility: hidden;
    }

}
```

This will hide the div with the ID of "video" for screensizes smaller than 500px (or whatever pixel width you determine).